# std::function as a parameter in delegate constructor

Tags: c++11, constructor, std-function

I want to know why control **does not** go to `AB()` if I pass in `abc(AB)` into `main()` as control goes for initialization of i as 10 when `abc(10)` is passed

```
class abc
{
    int i;
        
    std::function<void(void)>func = nullptr;
public:
    abc(){}
        
    abc(std::function<void(void)>&fb):func(fb){}
    
    abc(int i):i(i){}
};

void AB()
{
    cout<< "fun_AB";
}

int main()
{
    abc(AB);
    abc(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abc(AB);
```

This is a declaration of a variable of type `abc` named `AB`, equivalent to `abc AB;`. So the no-arg constructor is called. You could use this syntax if you don't want to name the variable:

```
abc{AB};
```

This "works" since it can't be parsed as a declaration, while your version can.

But that's not enough, you need to change your constructor to accept a `const&`:

```
abc(std::function<void(void)> const& fb) : func(fb)
{
  func(); // if you want AB to be called
}
```

(Non-const reference won't bind to a temporary.)

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is called with `AB` which is a function:

```
abc(std::function<void(void)>&fb) : func(fb) {}
```

This initializes `func` to point to `AB`, but nothing more.  Perhaps you wanted to call it:

```
abc(std::function<void(void)>&fb) : func(fb) { func(); }
```

Comment: '@John Zwinck' iam not getting the output by ur method..please suggest me better one